# Get Data from Website via NodeJS only one time

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I just want from these site: http://scripts.ivao-de.net/api/?type=training the h4 only ONE time. So I have only the first one what is displayed.

This code gives me all texts:

```
setInterval(() => {
        var d = new Date();
        if (d.getHours() === 21) {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://scripts.ivao-de.net/api/?type=training'
            }, (err, res, body) => {

                if (err) return console.error(err);

                let $ = cheerio.load(body);
                let title;

                if(isCheckedToday === false) {
                    title = $('h4');
                    isCheckedToday = true;     
                    console.log(title.text());
                }
            });
        } else {
            isCheckedToday = false;
        }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what is that you want to achieve and what is problem.

Comment: I want the data from the website but only the first div. Now there is 20.01.2020 1700z
ADC Training EDDT

this is what I want. ONLY the first div!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
title = $('h4').first();
```